# Getting individual results of aggregated TAP output from TAP::Harness

Tags: perl, testing, tap, tap-harness

I'm running some tests via TAP::Harness and now I'm trying to get all the individual results from the TAP parser. What I do is first run the tests:

```
my $harness = TAP::Harness->new( { verbosity => 1, lib => [ 'blib/lib' ] } );
my $aggregator = $harness->runtests( @tests );
```

This works great. Then I try to get the results out as per the TAP::Parser documentation:

```
my @results;

my @parsers = $aggregator->parsers;
foreach my $prsr( @parsers ) { 
    while( my $result = $prsr->next ) { 
        push @results, { type => $result->type,
                         ok   => $result->ok,
                         text => $result->as_string };
    }
}
```

However, this results in `@results` being an empty array.

If I `Dumper` the individual Parser objects, I can see that they have parsed the test results successfully:

```
  bless( {
           'tests_run' => 5,
           'actual_passed' => [
                                1,
                                2,
                                3,
                                4,
                                5
                              ],
  ....etc
```

I can't figure out how to get the test results out of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to get what I wanted by constructing the individual parsers manually and running them.

```
    foreach my $test( @tests ) { 
        my @test_results;
        my $parser = TAP::Parser->new( { source => $test } );
        while( my $result = $parser->next ) { 
            push @test_results, 
              { text => $result->as_string,
                ...
              }
        }
```

Then I suppose I can do the aggregation manually, though I'm still hoping there's a way to get the aggregated results and the actual TAP data from a single TAP::Harness instance. I haven't been able to figure that out, though.